# Daterangepicker can't select today's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I am using the daterangepicker control but I am unable to select the current data using the endDate moment switch. Is there anything else I need to add in order for users to be able to select the current date?

```
 $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
                opens: (Metronic.isRTL() ? 'left' : 'right'),
                startDate: moment().subtract('days', 7),
                endDate: moment(),
                minDate: $("#minDate").val(),
                //maxDate: '12/31/2014',
                maxDate: moment(), // 30 days from the current day
                //dateLimit: {
                //    days: 60
                //},
                showDropdowns: true,
                showWeekNumbers: true,
                timePicker: false,
                timePickerIncrement: 1,
                timePicker12Hour: true,
                ranges: {
                    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 7), moment()],
                    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 30), moment()],
                    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                    'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
                },
                buttonClasses: ['btn'],
                applyClass: 'green',
                cancelClass: 'default',
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                separator: ' to ',
                locale: {
                    applyLabel: 'Apply',
                    fromLabel: 'From',
                    toLabel: 'To',
                    customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
                    daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
                    monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                    firstDay: 1
                }
            },
                function (start, end) {
                    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                }
            );
            //Set the initial state of the picker label
            $('#reportrange span').html("Select Dates");
```

[image]